# pytorch load _IncompatibleKeys

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I trained a model of Efficentnet-b6(Architechture is as follows):

https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch

Now, I tried to load a model I trained with it:

```
checkpoint  = torch.load('model.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)
```

but then I got the following error:

```
_IncompatibleKeys
```

```
missing_keys=['_conv_stem.weight', '_bn0.weight', '_bn0.bias', ...]
unexpected_keys=['module._conv_stem.weight', 'module._bn0.weight', 'module._bn0.bias', ...]
```

Please let me know how can I fix that, what am I missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compare the `missing_keys` and `unexpected_keys`, you may realize what is happening.

```
missing_keys=['_conv_stem.weight', '_bn0.weight', '_bn0.bias', ...]
unexpected_keys=['module._conv_stem.weight', 'module._bn0.weight', 'module._bn0.bias', ...]
```

As you can see, the model weights are saved with a `module.` prefix.
And this is because you have trained the model with `DataParallel`.

Now, to load the model weights without using `DataParallel`, you can do the following.

```
# original saved file with DataParallel
checkpoint = torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

# create new OrderedDict that does not contain `module.`
from collections import OrderedDict

new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
for k, v in checkpoint.items():
    name = key.replace("module.", "") # remove `module.`
    new_state_dict[name] = v

# load params
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict, strict=False)
```

OR, if you wrap the model using `DataParallel`, then you do not need the above approach.

```
checkpoint  = torch.load('model.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)
```

Although the second approach is not encouraged (since you may not need `DataParallel` in many cases).